# WebForm_InitCallback is not defined

Tags: .net, ajax, webforms

Weird issue going on.  .NET 2.0 site using the System.Web.Extensions Version 1.0.61025.0 for some little AJAX stuff.  We have a Web Farm with 2 load balanced servers.  The site has been up for about 2 years now with no issues.  Currently the hosting company upgraded the Framework to 3.5 and now a page that is using an simple asp:Panel is not working.

Like always, it works fine on development and staging but not on production.  The page is not doing anything crazy.  There is not even an AJAX call on the page.

You can view the page here -> http://www.goplaylabels.com/CommunityInvolvement/FindaSchool.aspx

Any feedback or direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced this issue today. But the reason was quite weird. My system date was wrong and referring to 2002 Jan. The webform error got resolved once i updated my system date.

Answer (score 0):

I found most of solutions are the system data issue. But my date is right. I resolved this issue by reinstalling the .net framework.